# Write json-like data in padas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe:
`df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2], "b":[2,1]})`
and I'd like to create a new column with json-like structure in it (lists of objects).
But the problem is, that it has different length of lists.
like this:
`df['z'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.where(row.a>row.b, [{"c":row["b"]}], [{"d":1}, {"e":2}] ), axis=1)`
But I get an error

desired output is as follows:

| a | b | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | [{"d":1}, {"e":2}] |
| 2 | 1 | [{"c":1}] |

Comment: When you say JSON, you mean *a python list*, not *actual JSON*, correct?

Comment: In any case, it's not clear to me what you want... you want a list with `a` empty dicts in column z?

Comment: Anywhat, I'm not sure what you expect `np.where(2>1, ...)` to do.. `2>1` is just the `bool` object `True`....

Comment: 1. yes it is actualy a list but with json-like structure in it

Comment: 2. modified my examples a little. I'd like to have lists of different length in different rows, but it fails if I create them like this

Comment: stop talking about JSON, JSON is irrelevant here, you want a *list of dicts*. JSON is a text-based serialization format

Comment: Again, **what is the actual output you are expecting**. it isn't clear at all from the code you are *trying*, because using `np.where` here makes no sense. Can you just give an example input with the expected output (and a description of the logic...)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga edited. but the table collapsed ( in preview it was ok

Comment: So, if column `a` is greater than column `b`, you want `[{"c":1}]`, otherwise, `[{"c":1}]`? Then you can do something like `df.apply(lambda row: {"c":1}] if row['a'] > row['b'] else [{"d":1}, {"e":2}], axis=1)`

Comment: Yes this works! Better than np.where :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235955/discussion-between-denis-ka-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).